# ¿Por qué funciona esto?

Tags: c++

La sobrecarga del operador + recibe un objeto Punto, pero si hago la suma de Punto+Entero la realiza igual.

Método en el .cpp:

```
Punto Punto::operator+(Punto a){
   Punto aux;
   aux.mx=mx+a.mx;
   aux.my=my+a.my;
   aux.verificar();
   return aux;
}
```

main:

```
Punto A(10,20);
Punto B;
B=A+100;
cout<<B.getX()<<";"<<B.getY(); --> esto da 110;20
```

Constructores:

```
Punto(double x=0,double y=0);
Punto(const Punto &p);
```

Gracias

Comment: ¿ Podrías mostrar los **constructores** de la clase `Punto` ? No es necesario todo el código, solo como los defines.

Comment: Así definí los constructores:                                                                                            Punto(double x=0,double y=0);
Punto(const Punto &p);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu código funciona debido al casting implícito (de 100 a Punto) que el compilador hace cuando encuentra la operación aritmética A+100.
Esto ocurre porque el constructor definido como Punto(double x=0,double y=0) se comporta como constructor implícito ya que tiene valores por defecto para los parámetros de entrada.

Por lo tanto 100, después de la conversión implícita pasa a ser una instancia de objeto Punto con mx=100 y my=0.

PD: Además, no hay ningún tipo de problema a la hora de convertir un int a un double ya que no hay perdida de información en la conversión.

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda. David.

Comment: Muchas Gracias David!!!