# Duda con Ejercicio de sobrecarga de operador + y -

Tags: c++, operador, sobrecarga-de-operadores

El ejercicio me pide que la implementación de la suma y la resta se realice **cada una** con un solo método miembro. Y se tiene que poder ejecutar el siguiente código:

```
        int main()
        {
            Punto p(12.34,-56.78);
            Punto r,s;
            s=78+p;
            r=78-p;
            cout<<"1. punto p= ("<<p.getX()<<";"<<p.getY()<<")"<<endl;
            cout<<"2. punto 78+p: s= ("<<s.getX()<<";"<<s.getY()<<")"<<endl;
            cout<<"3. punto 78-p: r= ("<<r.getX()<<";"<<r.getY()<<")"<<endl;
            r=p+s-45;
            cout<<"4. punto p+s-45: r= ("<<r.getX()<<";"<<r.getY()<<")"<<endl;
        }
```

¿Cómo se puede hacer la sobrecarga del operador para que la operación se pueda hacer de las dos formas (`int+Punto` y `Punto+int`) con un solo método?

Comment: Esta pregunta: [¿Por qué funciona esto?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/155906/19610) es tuya también. Ya sabes como hacerlo.

Comment: Ya probé de diferentes formas y no funciona, la única forma que encontré es con 2 métodos, uno que tome Punto + int, y otro método friend de int + Punto. ¿Hay una forma de hacerlo en un solo método?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> El ejercicio me pide que la implementación de la suma y la resta se realice cada una con un solo método miembro.

No es lo mismo `int + Punto` que `Punto + int`. Estos casos van a ser tratados por funciones independientes. En el caso de la función miembro el operador, expresado de forma explícita, quedaría así:

```
Punto Punto::operator+(this,int);
```

Es facil ver que esta función no sirve para el caso `int + Punto` ya que no puedes convertir un entero en un punto y un punto en un entero... Para tratar el caso `int + Punto` necesitas, como hemos comentado, una función *amiga*:

```
class Punto
{
  friend Punto operator+(int,Punto const& punto); // funcion amiga

  // ...

  Punto operator+(int valor) const; // funcion miembro
};

Punto operator+(int valor, Punto const& punto)
{
  return punto + valor;
}

Punto Punto::operator+(int valor) const
{ /* ... */ }
```

Nota que la función no es miembro (y si intentas hacerla miembro tendrás un bonito error de compilación).

Comment: Muchas Gracias eferion!!!